# Any easier way to work with web animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, svg

I'm a beginner in web animations(canvas and svg). I have seen some work and examples in [Chrome Experiments](http://chromeexperiments.com) and am really excited to dive in. However, whenever I'm trying to do anything remotely decent or following any tutorial that seems a little bit interesting, the sheer amount javascript that has to be put in is proving to be a huge turn off.

For example, if I want to do any simple svg animation, I have to manually place the co-ordinates to achieve the effects. If there were any GUI tool to work with SVG or Canvas that would produce the initial movements(i.e. If I want to move an object from A to B, I'd like to do it by hand rather than counting the pixels) then the subsequent tweaking would be a lot easier. Are there any tools that help you achieve the effects? If not, **what's the standard way to draw and animate svg graphics/canvas animation today?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hype, Sencha Animator , Adobe Edge Animate are tool you might want to use if your purpose is to do animation with web technologies.

The problem with the link you provided is many of the exemples involve quite a lot of programming. It's not like Flash where you could do crazy stuffs with little programming knowledge. So you are not going to do crazy stuffs with any of the program I cited. By the way flash now exports to web techs so you might want to look into that.

You will have to write some javascript to make a decent animation with Canvas or SVG, as most of the previous software work with the DOM.

But you can cheat, a lot of agencies now use video (from After Effect) for animation directy, and you can manipulate video through canvas, do compositing etc ... the problem will be the size in that case.

Comment: So far SenchaAnimator seems to be the best answer to my needs. Thanks, great suggestion.